# react express Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I understand this error is not the reason for the failing.  It is failing because in my index.html file i have:

```
<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.f4a49fba.js"></script>
</body>
```

That script tag src is failing and returning the same file contents as the index.html itself.  This causes it to render HTML (hence < unexcpected from `<!DOCTYPE html>`).

I am trying to have both express server with /graphql and react together.  The working solution is using express.static middlewear shown below.  Problem is the working solution breaks the /graphql endpoint so I cannot return any data.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
```

I need to get this working so it first allows the previous enpoints (`/graphql`) before checking static pages so I am trying to use this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/') });
});
```

This is successfully getting pulled back but failing to work because `main.f4a49fba.js` in the script tag does not want to load.  I tried changing it to `/client/build/static/js/main.f4a49fba.js` but still wont load.  This is using a build file for production.

UPDATE:

I replaced my code with below which helped but for some reason even though I have /graphql above this it is still being run when a full address is being run.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const link = (req.path == '/' ? 'index.html' : req.path);
  const root = path.join(__dirname, 'client/build');
  res.sendFile(link, { root: root }, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.sendFile('/', { root: root });
    }
  });
});
```

I am getting this now when a graphql request comes in which seems like it is missing the first /graphql and going to my updated function above.  It is very strange and sticking the graphql full address at the end of whatever current page I am in.

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/accounts/my.herokuapp.com/graphql 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: How is your weback.config.js file looks like ? Are you using any webpack plugins like htmlwebpacklugin ?

Comment: i have the same problem and im using "customize-cra", any idea?